# Make next link to function in pagination

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wish to know how would manipulate the value of this variable

`cur` from `var cur = $("#currentPage").val();`

so that it changes to the next value every time i click a next link.

i.e.  `<a href="#" id="next"> more</a>`

**Fraction of javascript code**

```
$("#next").click(function(){

  Display_Load();
  var cur = $("#currentPage").val();
  var pageNum = Number(cur) + 1;
  $("#currentPage").val(pageNum);
  $("#contents").load("frontscroll.php?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());              

});
```

The main problem is that the variable **cur** does not move to the next value after i click the next link. hence the script does not load the next data.

Any help?

Comment: is the php tag necessary? there's no php to support the question.

Comment: Look at event propagation

Comment: @Fred-ii- mayb it might be. if it doesn't al remove

Comment: @krushiovida If someone posts an answer and it doesn't work, then it could be related to your php. If so, then you will need to update your question with the (php) and the tag. Plus, if it's db-related also. Let's see what the good folk will come up with for you ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hope i find

Comment: Look at your (developer) console and check for errors on PHP. If MySQL is used here also, then check for errors there also. That's the best I can offer here. Good luck, *cheers* @krushiovida

Comment: can u plz post the relevant HTML code?

Comment: @messerbill it has worked now. I found the solution. Thank you for being concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has worked after adding this code.

```
<input id="currentPage" value="1" />
```

somewhere in the html code.